# ORDER BY Variable issues

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2005

I'm having issues passing a variable to ORDER BY in an MSSQL query (through PHP), here the code:

```
    <?php
include "connection.php";
$type = $_POST['type'];
$order = $_POST['order'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

$params="@order varchar(10)";
$paramslist="@order=$order";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY "+@order;
$dbsql = "EXEC sp_executesql
N'$sql',
N'$params',
$paramslist";
$result = sqlsrv_query($link, $dbsql);
if ($result) {
echo "OK";
} else {
echo "FAIL - " . $order . " -- ";
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

I get the following error echoed to the browser:

> FAIL - CompanyName -- Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => 42000
>               [SQLSTATE] => 42000
>               [1] => 102
>               [code] => 102
>               [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '0'.
>               [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '0'.
>           )
>   )

Checks so far:

- All POST variables have the required data
- SQL table name correct and data in $order equals the correct column name

I've searched around but can't find anything too helpful, can anyone help?

Thank You.

EDIT:

Ok so code is now:

```
$params="@order varchar(10)";
$paramslist="@order=$order";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY ".$order;
$dbsql = "EXEC sp_executesql
N'$sql',
N'$params',
$paramslist";
$result = sqlsrv_query($link, $dbsql);
```

And it works fine, but does this leave it open to SQL injection attacks? Is there any better way of performing this query?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSSQL syntax, but shouldn't @order be part of the sql-string? `"SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY " @order;` => `"SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY @order;"`

Comment: .. or better `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY ".$order;`

Comment: dunno about your variable issues but this is apparently sql injection issue.

Comment: - or possibly `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY "+$order;`

Comment: Ive tried your suggestion Mark...it works, thanks...but doesn't this leave it more open to SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY  @order";
```

Since this doesn't work, the best way is to use prepared statements i think

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customer  WHERE value = ? ORDER BY ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['value'], $_POST['order']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
```

Comment: That would order by the constant value of `@order`

Comment: @cjk i thought that `@order` was passed as a parameter `$params="@order varchar(10)";
$paramslist="@order=$order";`

Comment: Edited main description, with latest test. Could this be an issue with the SQL permissions?

Comment: @DanHall no it seems that you can't use variables as you are doing, but you should check msdn for that error ('im no MSSQL expert)

Comment: It now works after changing the sql varible to:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY "+$order;

but i fear this leaves it more open to SQL injection, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @DanHall you areright, you should use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @DanHall i updated the answer with an example of a prepared statement

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Nicola, sorry but this is very new to me, would you be able to give me an example where there are two POST values passed into the statement e.g.

SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE value = 'variable1' ORDER BY 'variable2'

Many thanks.

Comment: @DanHall you could simply pass an array with more values: the first value replaces the first `?` , i updated my answer

Comment: Sorry one more question @NicolaPeluchetti, $dbh is an undefined variable, do you know how this should be defined. Bear in mind this is an MS-SQL query.

Comment: @DanHall Microsoft gives you [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098) driver for using PDO with SQL Server and you should study it. Otherwise you should use [ODBC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) but you should stick with PDO which is the standard

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with Sql Injection by using a code for the order by, e.g. you post back to yourself 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. which is converted in code to be the correct column name. If the code posted doesn't match your lookup, you ignore it.